# Система аутентификации для сайта

Tags: javascript, cookie, авторизация, аутентификация

Имеется сайт на javascripte, надо что бы была авторизация и регистрация, а если ты не залогинился - выкидывало на меню авторизации, интересно как это писать и что можно почитать, в моем текущем понимании информация о том, залогинин ты или нет просто сохраняется в куках, а аутентификацию можно просто делать через запрос в базу данных через ajax запрос или как-то придется приделать php ? В общем ищу что почитать, если что-то говорю не правильно, поправьте.

Comment: Самым правильным было бы рассказать и показать то, что сами попробовали сделать, а не просить помощи на пустом месте.

Comment: почитайте google.com или yandex.ru - и вперёд! какой вопрос - такой и ответ

Answer (score 0):

Есть такая штука у GOOGLE как Firebase. Через них можно реализовывать авторизацию без использования backend`а у себя, чисто на JS.
Почитай про это.